# Index scrolling problem with PageView.Builder()

Tags: flutter, pageviews, flutter-pageview

i´m trying to make a horizontal scrollable widget. it must be infinit (or kind of), so I´ve done this.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final int initialPage = 1000;

    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      height: 400,
      child: PageView.builder(
        controller: PageController(
          keepPage: true,
          initialPage: initialPage,
        ),

        itemBuilder: (context, position) {

          print(position);

          return Container(child:Text(position),
          );
        },
        itemCount: null,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Then i scroll right 3 times and the console shows this:

```
I/flutter (12616): 1000
I/flutter (12616): 1001
I/flutter (12616): 1002
I/flutter (12616): 1003
```

but then when i go backwards, i have to scroll 4 times to see some results, but in the middle it doesn´t show anything.

```
I/flutter (12616): 1000
I/flutter (12616): 1001
I/flutter (12616): 1002
I/flutter (12616): 1003
I/flutter (12616): 999
I/flutter (12616): 1004
I/flutter (12616): 1005
```

That was 3 times right, 4 times left and 6 to the right again. 
Why itemBuilder function doesn´t run sometimes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think that the reason is because the `print()` runs when the PageView builder has to `build` a new page.

When you go back (or forward), *and you go to a page that was already built*, the builder don't run again. (Nothing to build)

The pages 1003 1002 1001 1000 were already created when going back.

---

Please read this, from the documentation of [PageView.builder constructor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView/PageView.builder.html)

> Creates a scrollable list that works page by page using widgets that
>   are **created on demand**.
>
> This constructor is appropriate for page views with a large (or
>   infinite) number of children because the builder is called **only for
>   those children that are actually visible**.

Comment: Thanks! so now i use "onPageChange" to get the real position.